# middle of the page two divs one under the other

Tags: html, css

I want to put two divs one on top of the second one, in the middle of the page. One will contain text and the second an image. Sizes of the divs are different. First is wider and the second is taller. I need to use `z-index`, but how should I place two divs centered (inside third div 100% height and 100% width of the page? I can do it with `:after` but when they are the same shape but not when they are not the same shape).

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: no clear at all, do you mean something like  http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eBwrJK ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `<div>` elements are set to `display: block`, which means that each will appear on a separate line. If you want them to appear one above the other, just put them consecutively in your code. Next, you will only need to add this CSS:

```
myDiv {
  position: relative // static (default) also works here
  margin:   auto;
}
```

Comment: You do not need z-index

Comment: this is they way how to put one div above the other, but second thing i need is to put them both in the middle of other div. I've already tried few ways, but position relative broke all of methods and divs were not in the middle any more. This two things have to work together.

Answer (score 0):

finally i've made it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#textDiv').css('top',parseInt($('#externalContainer').css('height'))/2 - parseInt($('#textDiv').css('height'))/2 + 'px');
$('#picDiv').css('top',parseInt($('#externalContainer').css('height'))/2 - parseInt($('#picDiv').css('height'))/2 - parseInt($('#textDiv').css('height')) + 'px');
$('#textDiv').css('left',parseInt($('#externalContainer').css('width'))/2 - parseInt($('#textDiv').css('width'))/2 + 'px');
$('#picDiv').css('left',parseInt($('#externalContainer').css('width'))/2 - parseInt($('#picDiv').css('width'))/2 + 'px');
});
```